How to add buttons dynamically with flet (Python)?
I'm trying to add a new button to choose directory after choosing the perv direcotry (in order to choose multiple directories).
This select-directory button needs to appand everytime after I choose directory. How can I do that?
Edit:
Attaching my code here:
# Method to create a file picker
self.images_dir = FileChooseRow(
            "Images Folder",
            MetaFileType.DIRECTORY,
            pick_files_dialogs[0],
            fn_validate_submit,
)

def button_clicked(e):
            self.add_images_dir.data += 1
            self.row = ft.Row()
            self.row.update()

# create button to add another file picker on screen on run time
self.add_images_dir = ft.IconButton(
            icon="add", tooltip="Add", height=40, on_click=button_clicked, data=0
)
self.row = ft.Row()

I need something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/SP8de/

please provide the code you have so far.  Or please try to concisely explain what you are trying to accomplish.  It sounds like you perhaps want a select directory widget where you can select multiple directories?

Hi, just added my code @UpAndAdam

I guess this is what you want:

Press a "Chose directory button" (main button) to make another button appear.
Press the other button to chose a directory

I would firstly make a variable to store the added buttons and a row whose controls are set to the array. Then you can add your main button into it. Eg.
main_btn = ft.ElevatedButton(text="Chose directory")
added_btns = [main_btn]
r = ft.Row(added_btns)
page.add(r)

Next, make the callback for the main button
def add_button(e: ft.ControlEvent):

    def dir_btn_pressed(e: ft.ControlEvent):
        picker.ask_directory(initial_directory="...")

    new_btn = ft.TextButton(text="Chose Directory")
    new_btn.on_click=dir_btn_pressed
    added_buttons.append(new_btn)
    page.update()

main_btn.onclick = add_button

Now implement the directory picker:
def dir_picked(e: ft.FilePickerResultEvent):
    print(f"Picked {e.path}")

picker = ft.FilePicker(on_result=dir_picked)


You may have to fix the odd typo :)
